# Laravel 7 custom package - How to @include header and footer file?

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-7

We are building customize laravel package and try to include common header and footer file on the rest of the backend pages but it is not finding package path and going to the laravel root path.

We do not want to use publisher to clone all the file to the root resource directory.
We are getting following error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
View [header] not found.
```

Any help will appriciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#views
you can define the package view location using

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.



    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/courier'),
    ]);


They are using publishes to publish on the root laravel resource directory and they can access it easily but i don't want to use publishes.

Comment: `loadViewsFrom()` will achieve what you are requesting not `publishes()`